# Unexpected result, I obtain always 0 in row[2]. Why?

Tags: php

row[0] return giocatore’s field value
row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BhdS.jpg) return avversario’s field value
row[2] should return the values of “coins” field but it returns everytime value=0, WHY?

[Here it is an image of the table, the fields and the values that row[2] is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BhdS.jpg)

Everytime I call the function coins() in a php script that I created, it always returns me the third value of the row array with value 0 (so row[2] always = 0) but when I check the value of it on php-MyAdmin using the same SQL instruction I obtain the correct values (different by 0). So why PHP is not using the right value with row[2]. The values of row[0] and row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BhdS.jpg) are always correct in php-MyAdmin and in the script results.

This is the SQL statement I created and it seems to work fine on php-MyAdmin:`` SELECT `giocatore`, `avversario`, `coins` FROM `tiri_dadi_table2` WHERE `contatore`= (SELECT MAX(`contatore`) FROM `tiri_dadi_table2`) ``

The database name: is tiri_dadi_db

The Table name is: tiri_dadi_table2

Columns names are: 'contatore' int(11), 'giocatore' int(11), 'avversario' int(11), coins int(11)

In php, as a result of the row[2] always equal to 0 I have always DB_coins = 0 at the beginning of the function in my script, so it's increased or decreased and then return to be 0 everytime.

It seems to be a scope problem but I'm not able to solve it at the moment.

Thank you in advance for your help.
(sorry for my bad english, I'm working on it! :)

```
function coins() {
        /* Connect to the database */
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '');

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("<br>Connessione fallita: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
            //echo "<br>DB connesso con successo.<br>";

        // Select database
        mysqli_select_db($conn,"tiri_dadi_db");

    // sql READING values
    $sql = "SELECT `giocatore`, `avversario`, `coins` FROM `tiri_dadi_table2` WHERE `contatore`= (SELECT MAX(`contatore`) FROM `tiri_dadi_table2`)";
// on php-MyAdmin this SQL statement return me 3 correct values but here in the script, on the row[2] value there is always 0. Why??? Is a static problem or what?

    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $last_roll_R = $row[0];
        $last_roll_B = $row[1];
        $DB_coins = $row[2]; // ...... but this is 0 everytime even though in SQL give me the correct value...

var_dump($row); // The var_dump($row) return me something like this:
// array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "0" }

      }
      // free memory
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

...
}
```

Comment: Why are you silencing error reporting?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show and what does the direct query to the database show?

Comment: The var_dump($row) return me something like this:
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "0" }
The [2] always 0 but is not true this...

I silenced the error report for an old test, now I will remove @. But is not that the point..

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of you executing the same query through phpMyAdmin along with the results?

Comment: A data sample would do a lot of good to your question.

Comment: here is an example of the coin value on database, it is different by 0 but is always 0 my row[2] ... https://ibb.co/02HCMkm

Comment: In the second part of the function if you win the coins are increased and if you lose the coins are decreased. I use this other SQL statement to write into DB.
`UPDATE tiri_dadi_table2 SET `coins` = '$DB_coins' WHERE `contatore`= (SELECT MAX(`contatore`) FROM `tiri_dadi_table2`)`



The DB is modified but when the row[2] is returned is always 0, so the coins never really change each time. Like in a scope problem, where the var lose his value out of the function.